# ASP.NET Server Controls Showing Out Of Context Msg

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was working with this simple web page and happened to put some 's to correct the styling of my page and suddenly when got back to programming in the .cs file, things are strange. All the code is showing a similar error msg:

Error 2 The name 'TextBox1' does not exist in the current context d:\ADO_NETprojects\mywebsite\Default2.aspx.cs

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs"     `enter code here`Inherits="Default2" %>
```

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  <title></title>
   </head>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div runat="server">

    <div>
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="179px"     style="margin-left:100px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    </asp:ListBox>
     </div>

     <hr/>
     <div>
     ListBoxItems 
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px;"></asp:TextBox>
     </div>

     <div>
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        style="height: 26px; margin-left:100px; margin-top:15px;" Text="ListsBoxItems"  />
     </div>
     <hr/>


     <div>
     DeleteItems:
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="margin-top:10px; margin-     left:25px;"></asp:TextBox>
     </div>
     <hr/>

     <div>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
             style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:100px; width:200px;" 
            AutoPostBack="True"      onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
     </asp:DropDownList>
     </div>

     <div>
     DropDownList:
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" style="margin-left:2px; margin-top:15px;" 
            AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
     </div>
     <hr/>


    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: did you remove the designer page ?

Comment: Delete and regenerate `Default2.aspx.Designer.cs`

Comment: @Kumar Manish, No I didn't remove the designer page.

Comment: @Bharadwaj, how do i regenerate Default2.aspx.Designer.cs??

Comment: go with @Bharadwaj advice

Comment: right-click on the aspx file, then choose "convert to web application" and then, the designer.cs file is regenerated

Comment: @Kumar Manish, Thanks for the prompt reply, it helped a lot.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right-click on the aspx file, then choose "convert to web application" and then, the designer.cs file is regenerated